# iframe tags style don’t working with @media query

Tags: html, css, iframe

When the screen width is more than 700px, the **iframe** tags width will be 400px and height will be 225px. If the screen width is less then 700px, then **iframe** tags width will be **50%** of the screen and height will be 28.13% of the screen.

I tried with this ↓ code. But it doesn’t work.

```
@media (max-width:700px){.video-container2{
  width: 50%;
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 28.13%;
  height: 0;
}.video-container2 iframe{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}}
```

```
<div style="display: flex; padding: 8px; width: 100%">
    
    <div class="video-container2">
        <iframe frameborder="1" width="400px" height="255px"
        src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/kBcLgP4WJ4I"></iframe>
    </div>
    
    <div style="padding-left: 8px; width: 49.99%;">
        <h5 style="margin-top: -8px;">hwgh hwhwfhwlfhw lgw lh wlh lwfwf</h5>
        <p style="margin-top: -8px; font-size: 10px;">Channel name</p>
        <p style="margin-top: -12px; font-size: 8px;">101 views.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Where is the problem?

Comment: Height value in your code snippet is 255 while say "height will be 225px." Isn't it just a typing error?

Answer (score 0):

Hm, I think you have overlooked something. Because since you have already defined the appropriate size (255px) in the iframe HTML, it goes ahead in the iframe accordingly.

Greetings, Chris

Comment: This answer is not useful